# Dynamically set variable content in Ansible playbook for ufw task

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm currently trying to find a way to dynamically create some firewall rules (with the ufw ansible module) on some hosts. In the current context, we're talking about a docker swarm.

What I want to do is to create a set of rules (different protocols, ports) per source ip, but to have that dynamically expand with the number (and IP) of host, so that whatever is the amount or IP of the nodes, it always ends up creating one set of rule PER node on each node. Ideally, I would be able to exclude the current host it's running on as well.

I'm not very familiar with ansible and I'm not sure it's possible, as it would probably require to loop within a loop when creating the rules.
I've tried to join the address within the group with  `ip_swarm: "{{groups['all']|join(',') }}"` but ufw doesn't allow you to create rules that way and require one line per port/ip/proto it would seem (or ansible does, but looking at the code for the module, it seems to be ufw).

I'm assuming if there is a way, this is with some jinja loop in defining variables ? Or maybe with_subelements ?

Here's my current code, though that won't help as this was made for the case of a variable holding a string with comma separated values for IPs :

```
- name: Regles pare feu pour docker swarm
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    direction: "{{ item.direction }}"
    proto: "{{ item.proto }}"
    port: "{{ item.port }}"
    from_ip: "{{ item.from_ip }}"
    state: reloaded
  loop:
    - direction: "in"
      proto: "tcp"
      port: "2377"
      from_ip: " {{ ip_swarm }}"
    - direction: "in"
      proto: "tcp"
      port: "7946"
      from_ip: " {{ ip_swarm }}"
    - direction: "in"
      proto: "udp"
      port: "7946"
      from_ip: " {{ ip_swarm }}"
    - direction: "in"
      proto: "udp"
      port: "4789"
      from_ip: " {{ ip_swarm }}"
```

Here you go :) If you have some kind of idea, I'll gladly take it. Have a good day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out it was much simpler than what I intended. Ansible does have nested loop, with either `with_nested`, or by using non depreceated options, `loop` with the `product` filter (the first option being easier to read). See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html

My vars file that contains the FW parameters (for indication) :

```
---
liste_regle_pare_feu:
  - direction: "in"
    proto: "tcp"
    port: "2377"
  - direction: "in"
    proto: "tcp"
    port: "7946"
  - direction: "in"
    proto: "udp"
    port: "7946"
  - direction: "in"
    proto: "udp"
    port: "4789"
```

and the task itself :

```
- name: Regles pare feu pour docker swarm
  ufw:
    rule: allow
    direction: "{{ item.1.direction }}"
    proto: "{{ item.1.proto }}"
    port: "{{ item.1.port }}"
    from_ip: "{{ item.0 }}"
  loop: "{{ groups['all']|product(liste_regle_pare_feu)|list }}"
```

the loop will, for each item in the first object (here `groups['all']`, the list of all IPs), iterate over my rule list (of hashtables). See documentation for details on product filter

Comment: Also, I wanted to be able to use the hostname in the inventory, so here's how you can resolve the DNS hostname to the ip : `from_ip: "{{ lookup('dig',item.0) }}"` (same code)

Comment: Also, should one want to handle the possibility of either IP or DNS name, use if/else : `from_ip: "{{ item.0 if (item.0 | ipv4) else lookup('dig',item.0) }}`